# Excel - How to count character occurrence in strings in ranges of variable lengths

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

**Background:** I'm analyzing the frequency at which topics appear in a set of e-mails. Each topic has a corresponding character (a-z), and each e-mail was assigned several of these characters whenever some aspect of the topic came up:

[image: Basic structure of the data]

In the example above, MAIL2 touched upon the topic 'c' 2 times and 'd' 2 times.

**Question:** How do I sum up these occurrences *for each e-mail separately* if the number of rows and characters that corresponds to each e-mail is unpredictable (between 1 and ~12)?

I'm thinking about formatting the results like this:
[image]

I can give each row its corresponding e-mail label. I guess I would then have each grey cell count occurrence of one character (e.g. 'a' for `C2`) found in some sort of string concatenated from all cells that are in rows marked as MAIL1? But I will be grateful for any sort of solution that allows separate results for each e-mail.

Comment: If your data input is fixed, then I suggest you develop a VBA solution.  If your data input is flexible, then design one that is amenable to a pivot table -- eg:  data for each item in a row, and only a single character per cell, or all the characters in a single cell (then split it with power pivot)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the formulae in this answer need to be entered in cell `C2`, then copied/filled as required.

---

**EDIT:** Turns out there *is* a way to solve the problem without using helper cells:

```
=
SUMPRODUCT(
  ($B2=$A$2:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("*",$B:$B,-1)))*
  (LEN($B$2:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH("*",$B:$B,-1)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B$2:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH("*",$B:$B,-1)),C$1,"")))
)
```

Explanation: The `$A$2:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("*",$B:$B,-1))` term, and the corresponding `B` column version, is used to dynamically adjust the source ranges. The formula is equivalent to the following static version applicable to the example spreadsheet:

```
=
SUMPRODUCT(
  ($B2=$A$2:$A$11)*
  (LEN($B$2:$B$11)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$11,C$1,"")))
)
```

---

The simplest solution would be the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$B2,$B:$B,"=*"&C$1&"*")
```

Unfortunately this fails for the special case where there is more than one of any letter in a cell. For example, the 'f' in cell `B11` would only be counted once.

We *can* solve this issue in an ugly and limited way by summing the counts of multiple occurrences. For example, the following will work for up to a maximum of three occurrences of any character:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$B2,$B:$B,"=*"&C$1&"*")
+COUNTIFS($A:$A,$B2,$B:$B,"=*"&C$1&"*"&C$1&"*")
+COUNTIFS($A:$A,$B2,$B:$B,"=*"&C$1&"*"&C$1&"*"&C$1&"*")
```

Alternatively, we could use helper cells. The following formula copied/filled into every cell in the range `C2:H11` does just that:

```
=
IF(
  ""<>$A2,
  LEN($B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B2,C$1,"")),
  SUMIF($A:$A,$B2,C:C)
)
```

**Brief Explanation:**

`""<>$A2` selects whether the cell is a helper cell (true) or a grey, result cell (false).

`LEN($B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B2,C$1,""))` calculates the number of occurrences of the appropriate letter in the appropriate cell.

`SUMIF($A:$A,$B2,C:C)` sums the counts for the appropriate letter.